# Is there a standard solution for TextBox watermark/placeholder text in XAML in a VS C# .Net Core WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

So I am new to WPF and XAML, but all I am trying to do is add some placeholder text to a TextBox in a standard form. For example, "First name" will show in the TextBox when the app starts. When the user clicks in that TextBox, "First name" disappears and the user can freely enter their name. If the user then clicks away without typing anything yet, the placeholder text reappears. But if they started typing and *then* click away, what they typed still stays and is not lost.

I thought that this feature would be something that Visual Studio would have built in for TextBoxes or some other thing from the Tool Kit already but if it is I can't find it. I have tried all sorts of messing with the text or content of a textblock, etc.

One solution that I have found that is not ideal is as follows: I created a User Control with two TextBoxes - one for the user's input and one for the placeholder text. Depending on if the user input has focus or if the placeholder text loses focus, the placeholder text will/won't show. The functionality is correct, but there is still one problem. I cannot change the placeholder text at will in my MainWindow.xaml or else I lose the ability to even click into the TextBox in my form. Therefore, I would have to create a User Control for every variation of a TextBox that I would need throughout the application. I feel that I should be able to make the User Control with a variable text, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Is this really the best solution or is there something else I can do? I feel like I must be making this more complicated than it really is, but I cannot find a better solution anywhere.

My User Control xaml file

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Garamond"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="userInput" Height="15.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LostFocus="userInput_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="waterMarkText" Height="15.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Search" GotFocus="waterMarkText_GotFocus"/>
</Grid>
```

My User Control xaml.cs file

```
private void userInput_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Text))
        {
            userInput.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            waterMarkText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }

    private void waterMarkText_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        waterMarkText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        userInput.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        userInput.Focus();
    }
```

How I use the User Control

```
<local:WMTextBox x:Name="TBFirstName" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,2" 
                         Opacity =" .65" Cursor="IBeam" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
```

Comment: wpf does not have "forms".  The proper terminology is "window".

Comment: Yeah, I am creating a form that is in a WPF window. My bad if that was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-template a wpf control entirely.

WPF controls are "lookless" meaning that they have fixed behaviour but no specific template. You can replace the template for a wpf control. This has some implications which devs new to wpf often don't appreciate.

Templates would usually go in a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml. For our quick and dirty demo purposes here I've got a template in app.xaml.

```
         xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="WatermarkedTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Name="wm" 
                    Foreground="Gray"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    FontWeight="Bold" 
                    FontSize="10" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text,
                                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text,
                                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>

            </Grid>
        </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The above gives a textblock behind a textbox. The background of the textbox hides the textblock if the textbox has any content.  The text of the textblock is bound to the tag of the control being templated.

Like I say, this is quick and dirty so I'm using Tag which is an existing dependency property that's kind of going spare on a textbox. A more elegant solution would use an attached property for the watermark or inherit and extend.

Here's my textbox:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="txtCity" 
             Template="{StaticResource WatermarkedTextBoxTemplate}" 
             Tag="Please Enter First Name" 
             Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"  
             />
```

Comment: This seems to be helping. I knew there was something I was missing. I've been reading about control templates and binding, etc. since you posted. Seems like a lot of work just to add placeholder text though. In any case, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I'm still pretty new as well and had the same problem, I stumbled upon this after searching for a while.

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="placeholderString"/>
```

source
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.placeholdertext

Comment: The question is for WPF. The link you provided is for UWP which is a completely different framework.